# How to report a list in Behaviorspace NetLogo?

Tags: list, csv, netlogo

I am running a NetLogo model in BehaviorSpace each time varying number of runs. I have turtle-breed pigs, and they accumulate a table with patch-types as keys and number of visits to each patch-type as values.

In the end I calculate a list of mean number of visits from all pigs. The list has the same length as long as the original table has the same number of keys (number of patch-types). I would like to export this mean number of visits to each patch-type with BehaviorSpace.

Perhaps I could write a separate csv file (tried - creates many files, so lots of work later on putting them together). But I would rather have everything in the same file output after a run.

I could make a global variable for each patch-type but this seems crude and wrong. Especially if I upload a different patch configuration.

I tried just exporting the list, but then in Excel I see it with brackets e.g. [49 0 31.5 76 7 0].

**So my question Q1**: is there a proper way to export a list of values so that in BehaviorSpace table output csv there is a column for each value?

**Q2**: Or perhaps there is an example of how to output a single csv that looks exactly as I want it from BehaviorSpace?

PS: In my case the patch types are costs. And I might change those in the future and rerun everything. Ideally I would like to have as output: a graph of costs vs frequency of visits.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lists are a fixed length that doesn't vary from run to run, you can get the items into separate columns by using one metric for each item. So in your BehaviorSpace experiment definition, instead of putting `mylist`, put `item 0 mylist` and `item 1 mylist` and so on.

If the lists aren't always the same length, you're out of luck. BehaviorSpace isn't flexible that way. You would have to write a separate program (in the programming language of your choice, perhaps NetLogo itself, perhaps an Excel macro, perhaps something else) to postprocess the BehaviorSpace output and make it look how you want.

Comment: Thanks, it works for same length lists. 
Sorry that didn't think of it.
As for varying length - well - out of luck. I've been using the Excel "text to columns" for that but wanted to save the pain.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about "text to columns". Glad you mentioned it; that should be useful to others who happen upon this question.